# Visual studio 2017 отладка

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image: Скрин]

Как запустить программу в visual studio на с++ ?
Нигде не найду в настройках, нет такой возможности попросту запустить код
В чем может быть проблема, и как решить? Там где иконка запуска есть только "присоединение" но это явно не то что нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы открываете `.cpp` файл, который содержит только код. А вам нужно открыть `.sln` файл, который откроет все решение, если, конечно, оно существует. Если нет, то создайте новый проект и добавьте в него данный файл.

Answer (score 6):

По всей видимости нужно предварительно создать проект, в него добавить Ваш *.cpp файл и пробовать собрать весь проект. 
Воспользуйтесь шаблоном проекта

```
File -> New Project -> Win32 Console Application
```

Comment: А если нет такого пункта при создании проекта?